# Anyone know how to install NVidia drivers on fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install on laptop with NVidia gcard and AMD processor?

Tags: drivers, nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-16.04, asus-laptop

I install ubuntu I see the resolution is totally messed up and also the laptop begins to heat up a lot. I investigate and I determine that I must install gcard drivers. Ok, simple enough. I look up how to install drivers and follow instructions and I am stucked in infinite log-in loop. I look up how to solve *that* issue and either the resolution never is fixed or I am stucked in infinite log-in. So my question is this: How do I install the correct driver? How do I know if the driver is installed correctly? I mean, will the resolution be fixed as soon as I reboot with the correct driver or do I have to set that myself once the driver is installed? Will the laptop always be overheating? Been troubleshooting this a week :c anything helps, I tried these:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/

http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux

https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032384/linux/login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-390-48-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-notebook-asus-rog-with-1050ti-/

Specs: 2 ssds (one for Windows one for Ubuntu), AMD R7 3750H, NVidia 1660 Ti Max-Q

Comment: Add the graphics drivers ppa to obtain the version  you need that isn't available in the Ubuntu repository for 16.04. Then open Additional Drivers, select the newest version,  apply and reboot. It's  that simple but it should be said that a newer Ubuntu release is better for your hardware.

Comment: Hello @GabrielaGarcia, thank you for your reply. I will attempt this later today, I tried PPA but then I did a different sequence so maybe that's why it didn't work. I must use 16.04 since I use ROS Kinetic, I tried using Melodic but I couldn't get it to work, for some reason. I'll try that as well, later.

Comment: @phantomBlurrr Hey - I just got the same setup as you - GA502DU with same specs. I'm wondering, have you tried using virtualBox(Ubuntu 18.04) on Win10 - I'm getting tons of BSODs.

Comment: @AlfroJang80, I haven't tried virtual box and as of right now I have found no solution to drivers for this laptop :/ :/

Comment: @phantomBlurrr Ah. That's a bummer dude. I managed to get my VM working anyways (just happened to be my Avast antivirus with hardware virtualisation enabled on it)